# Bootstrap: How do I align the button correctly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The button in the jsFiddle below is vertical aligned with the labels. That doesn't look good and I would like it to align with the select box instead.

How do I do that?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpurv0L9/2/)

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="bookingForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Sender</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a sender</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Receiver</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a receiver</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Delivery</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a delivery address</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Manage customers...</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by align it with the select box? if you are looking to add some `margin-top` to take it off the select box. then that should be simple enough.

Comment: I really wish there should be a new rule, about multiple answers of exactly the same thing. I removed my answer because I realised it was the same as others had said. If only others could do the same, it would really tidy things up.

Comment: @Andrew: yes, I could add a margin-top but being new to bootstrap I am not sure that that is the "bootstrap" way of doing it. Should perhaps have said that in my question.

Comment: add unique id to button, and give it margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

1. add one label tag above the button with space (no content)
2. inside button use the class form-control.

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="bookingForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Sender</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a sender</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Receiver</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a receiver</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Delivery</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a delivery address</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Manage customers...</button>
      </div>      
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is invalid, and the form-control isn't needed

Comment: if we not use form-control that one not working  Lee. check the code after removed form-control

Comment: `form-control` has no effect on the display of the button. That class isn't meant to be used for buttons. The label above should be the only addition needed. And like I said, your code is invalid... you have two sets of double quotes after `form-control`

Comment: Ram_UI is right, it does not work without form-control. However, you are right about the the extra double qoute.

Answer (score 2):

I personally wouldn't add the margin-top, if you can avoid it. Purely down to the fact that when you look at it on a different device you will probably need to remove said margin.

I would add an "empty" form label above the button:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="bookingForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Sender</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a sender</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Receiver</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a receiver</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Delivery</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a delivery address</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label class="control-label" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Manage customers...</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted my answer without seeing this first, I'll remove mine. No need for it to be said twice :)

Comment: I think a lot of us had the same idea at exactly the same second!

Comment: there is no space between the delivery input and button

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of the hidden label myself! Btw, the button is not aligned correctly. Either put a DIV around the button or use the form-control class as suggested by Ram_UI.

Comment: @Birksy89. The button is only aligned correctly on smaller screens, otherwise it floats upwards like in my original code. A DIV around the button  solves it.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see now - I have done this in the past to fix:

<label class="control-label" style="
    display: block;
">&nbsp;</label>

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox, I find myself coming back to how good it is over and over again.

So what we want if for the button to move down so it's against the bottom of the block, not the top. We could move it a number of ways, but they all rely on you getting the number of pixels or percent right, and that seems like a lot of effort.

Here's the flexbox 'lazy' solution

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.form-group {
  display: flex;
}
.form-group .flex-down {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form id="bookingForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Sender</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a sender</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Receiver</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a receiver</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="control-label">Delivery</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a delivery address</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 flex-down">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Manage customers...</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope you find this helpful.

I added this to the CSS

`.form-group {
  display: flex;
}
.form-group .flex-down {
  align-self: flex-end;
}`

and the class `flex-down` to the div containing the button.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about flexbox. It's a very helpful class / method.

Answer (score 0):

do this as said by @Andrew,

```
button{
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 25px top margin to your button .

```
.btn-primary {
   margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the Y position using `transform: translateY(75%);`. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/fpurv0L9/3/)

Add below code to your CSS:

```
button {
  transform: translateY(75%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't change the button margin as it will affect every button.

How about adding an invisible label and the button take all the space of the column? I think it looks nicer on devices too.

See example bellow:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dhanck/fpurv0L9/7/

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
            <label style="visibility:hidden">das</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-group-justified">Manage customers...</button>
 </div>
```